# Problem when selecting a district, it only selects 1 because when selecting another one to compare, the following error occurs in shiny app

Tags: shiny, raster, reactive, shapefile

The first table comes out well at the time of execution, since I add the filter() function, which is a shapefile of the boundaries for each district. However when I select a new district with the purpose of comparing the changes in surface, I get the error shown in figure 2. This is because it can not add the name district1,2,3 etc, because they have the same VALUE and can not separate in a row? I hope you understand. Any help, I did with dplyr::bins_cols, but without success.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)
library(terra)
library(DT)
library(tibble)

cambio <-raster("cambio_cbba.tif") 
Distrito <- st_read("B_DISTRITO.shp")
Distrito1 <- Distrito %>% st_transform(crs=4326)

#---- Diseño----
ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(
      selectInput("distritos", "Seleccione el Distrito", 
                                  choices = unique(Distrito1$Distrito), 
                                  selected = "Distrito 1",
                                   multiple = TRUE)),
      
      dashboardBody(leafletOutput("mapa"),DTOutput("tabla"))
  
)

#---- Servidor----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
#---- Filtro ---- 
  filtro <- reactive({Distrito1 %>%dplyr::filter(Distrito %in% req(input$distritos) )})
  
#---- Raster ----  
  cambio_corte <-reactive({raster::crop(cambio, filtro())})
  cambio_mascara <-reactive({raster::mask(cambio_corte(), filtro())})

#---- Mapa ----  
  output$mapa <- renderLeaflet({
    
    #colores <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis", values(cambio_mascara()), na.color = "transparent")
    colores <- colorNumeric(palette = c("#D2CFCE", "#FCDD0F", "#287DFC"), domain = NULL, na.color = 'transparent')
    
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>% 
      addRasterImage(cambio_mascara(), colors = colores, opacity = 1) %>% 
      addPolygons(data=filtro()) %>% 
      #leaflet::addLegend(pal = colores, title = "Cambios", values =values(cambio_mascara()))
      leaflet::addLegend(colors = c("#D2CFCE", "#FCDD0F", "#287DFC"), labels = c("Sin Cambio", "Nuevo","Existente"))
    
  })
#---- Tabla----
  proj <-  "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  cambio1 <-reactive({projectRaster(cambio_mascara(), crs = proj, res = 30) })
  
  f <- reactive({freq(cambio1())})
  f1 <- reactive({as.data.frame(f())})
  f2 <- reactive({f1()[-4,]})
  f3 <- reactive({f2() %>% dplyr::mutate(area=f2()$count*0.09) %>% 
                            dplyr::mutate(filtro())})
 
  output$tabla <- renderDT({
  
  DT::datatable(f3())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```